# Large desktop on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, desktop

I would love to be able to augment the resolution of my desktop larger than that of my monitor.

Currently I am limited by the max resolution of my monitor.

In a previous laptop (toshiba) running WinXP, I was able to go beyond the monitor resolution, I get a big desktop where I can see only part of it with my monitor. I want this on my HP tm2 Win7. Is this possible?

Comment: This doesn't actually make sense to me... You want to scroll around to see your desktop or you want multiple virtual desktops? Please fill in the blanks and add examples if you can

Comment: Seems clear to me that he's asking how to enable desktop-panning (as opposed to multiple virtual desktops): "a big desktop where i can see only part of it with my monitor". Perhaps I'm the one who's confused, though. Alas, I have no real idea how to do this (panning, not being confused) in windows. A quick search suggested this commercial (with a free limited version) desktop extender: http://gimespace.com/gms3d.html and, if you've got an ATI GPU, perhaps it's directly available in the Catalyst driver config.

Comment: You are right SuperMagic, that what i want. i will try that

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you want in this case, but here's my best guess.

Go into Screen Resolution in Windows 7, you can select the display that you want to change by clicking its icon. From there you can set the resolution of that particular display. If you don't see the resolution you're looking for, you can go into *Advanced Settings* > *List All Modes* and from there you can select from all of the resolutions/refresh rates available. Under *Monitor* tab you can also untick the box that says *Hide modes that this monitor cannot display* and it will provide additional modes for you.

**Warning:**
Messing around with settings your monitor isn't capable of handling can damage the monitor. Use caution when doing so.

Comment: Hi, Will.B; the maximum i get by doing all of this is the resolution of the monitor, i want to go beyond that

Answer (score 1):

Download [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) and create a custom profile with as large a resolution as you want. Update your monitor driver with the one you just created and you should be able to select this new, larger, resolution in the same dialog you normally use to change screen resolution.

Source: http://www.techimo.com/forum/graphics-cards-displays/189029-i-want-desktop-larger-than-monitor-can-display-how.html#post3127045