# Is there any way to make Windows 7 desktop look like Metro UI of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, modern-ui

Imagine there is a slider in your desktop on Windows 7 and you can slide to right or left sides. Like an extended desktop. For example like 4000 x 1080 pixels.

Is it possible? Any software that makes it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Large desktop on windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/587532/large-desktop-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, i.e. with utilities like GiMe Space ( http://www.gimespace.com/ ) but it depends on the system; some laptops come with it too. Please keep in mind that questions for software recommendations generally get closed here.  You may find packages by searching for "virtual desktop 'windows 7'" or similar.  The free version of GiMe Space seems to support horizontal scrolling, which is all you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

[WinMetro](http://www.iobit.com/iobit-winmetro.php) is specially designed to bring the newly introduced Windows 8 Metro UI to Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP. It offers an easy solution for old versions of Windows users to try and enjoy the tile based Metro UI.

[Mosaic](http://mosaicproject.codeplex.com/) is a free utility that brings Windows 8 style Live tiles with Metro UI on Windows 7 Desktop. Its a set of live widgets which shows various useful content like weather, clock from the web on your Desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not want the METRO UI really. Maybe my question was not properly asked. I only want to extend my desktop.

Comment: @KorayTugay I think the title of your question was therefore phrased incorrectly.